# 'No basic auth credentials' when using amazon-ecr-credential-helper

Tags: docker, aws-ecr

I'm trying to setup the [amazon-ecr-credential-helper](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper) 
but always get `no basic auth credentials` when I try to `docker pull`.

When I use `aws ecr get-login` and `docker login ...` then I have no problems.

I followed the instructions in their README file using the docker image to create the binary.

In the troubleshooting section they say that a log file should be stored in `~/.ecr/log` but the `/.ecr` folder doesn't exist.

Specs:
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

aws-cli/1.16.31 Python/2.7.15 Darwin/17.4.0 botocore/1.12.21

MacOS High Sierra

I hope somebody has an idea to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: It sounds like the Docker CLI is not invoking the credential helper.  Have you ensured that the `docker-credential-ecr-login` binary is present in your `PATH` and is marked as executable?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by ensuring, the file ~/.docker/config.json was of the following content:

```
{
    "credsStore": "ecr-login"
}
```

This did **not** work for me:

```
{
    "credHelpers": {
        "aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login"
    }
}
```